# How to format a unix timestamp in a mysql query and strip the suffix?

Tags: mysql, database, date

I am trying to get the unix_timestamp from a date value saved in mysql db:

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
| unix_timestamp(fieldset_change_tracker_value) |
+-----------------------------------------------+
|                             1635264826.000000 |
|                             1635267128.000000 |
|                             1635353143.000000 |
+-----------------------------------------------+

 select unix_timestamp(fieldset_change_tracker_value) from node_revision__fieldset_change_tracker;
+-----------------------------------------------+
| unix_timestamp(fieldset_change_tracker_value) |
+-----------------------------------------------+
|                             1635264826.000000
```

What does the suffix `.000000` mean and how can I strip it out from the value?

Answer (score 2):

It's the microseconds in the time. You can use `ROUND()` to convert to an integer.

```
select ROUND(unix_timestamp(fieldset_change_tracker_value)) from node_revision__fieldset_change_tracker;
```